# How to design an ads auction service like google Adsense?

Tags: architecture, scalability, adsense, google-ads-api

I was going through google Ad auction service https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/160525?hl=en and wondering how one can design such large scale computational system. It has mostly read operation and pricing calculation . Memory Grid is one way to go and blackboard style solution mechanism need to apply .